# oracle 11g application express interface virtual column that calculates total amount of sales

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

Im currently working on my interface project by editing a certain page item of a form in oracle 11g application express. Im in confusion that one of the column is derived from another column in the table, does not work properly when i tried to register a new data through the interface. the column cannot calculate the derived data just like how it works in the oracle sql developer. i set the column as follows:

Im clueless, that should i display the column as hidden, or it has something to do with the source settings that needs PL/SQL expression to calculate the values of quantity, and cost_perunit column for total_amount values automatically. I have searched the web for the solution, but cant find a solution and a related issue to this.

*this command was uploaded in a text .txt format into the application express*

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT(
PAY_ID NUMBER(25)NOT NULL,
PAY_DATE DATE,
PAY_METHOD VARCHAR2(50 char),
SPARE_TYPE VARCHAR2(50 char),
QUANTITY NUMBER(12),
COST_PERUNIT NUMBER(6,2),
TOTAL_AMOUNT as (quantity*cost_perunit),
CONSTRAINT PAY_PK PRIMARY KEY(PAY_ID)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE pay_id_seq START WITH 400;
```

Im referring to the TOTAL_AMOUNT as (quantity*cost_perunit) column that returns error when i try to create a new data through the form. what should i change in the page edit settings, so it will work as it supposed to be.

Comment: I think perhaps you should also tag your Question with oracle-apex (I assume that is relevant for "oracle 11g application express")

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices create a table without virtual column calculate total amount at run time

e.g `select a.*,(quantity*cost_perunit) total_amount from payment a;`

or create table with virtual column with keyword `virtual`

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT(
PAY_ID NUMBER(25)NOT NULL,
PAY_DATE DATE,
PAY_METHOD VARCHAR2(50 char),
SPARE_TYPE VARCHAR2(50 char),
QUANTITY NUMBER(12),
COST_PERUNIT NUMBER(6,2),
TOTAL_AMOUNT as (quantity*cost_perunit) VIRTUAL, 
CONSTRAINT PAY_PK PRIMARY KEY(PAY_ID));

@ddl payment

    DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_NAME,OWNER)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
          CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."PAYMENT"
           (    "PAY_ID" NUMBER(25,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
                "PAY_DATE" DATE,
                "PAY_METHOD" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
                "SPARE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
                "QUANTITY" NUMBER(12,0),
                "COST_PERUNIT" NUMBER(6,2),
                "TOTAL_AMOUNT" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("QUANTITY"*"COST_PERUNIT") VIRTUAL ,
                 CONSTRAINT "PAY_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PAY_ID")
          USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255
          TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE"  ENABLE
           ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED
          PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
         NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
          TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE" ;

SQL> insert into payment (pay_id,pay_date,pay_method,spare_type,quantity,cost_perunit)
  2  values
  3  (&pid,&pdt,&pmethod,&spare,&qty,&cpu);
Enter value for pid: 101
Enter value for pdt: sysdate
Enter value for pmethod: 'CASH'
Enter value for spare: 'CREDIT CARD'
Enter value for qty: 12
Enter value for cpu: 1.9

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
SQL> /
Enter value for pid: 102
Enter value for pdt: sysdate-1
Enter value for pmethod: 'DEBIT CARD'
Enter value for spare: 'CREDIT CARD'
Enter value for qty: 21
Enter value for cpu: 2.99

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.


SQL> select * from payment;

    PAY_ID PAY_DATE            PAY_METHOD                                         SPARE_TYPE                                           QUANTITY COST_PERUNIT TOTAL_AMOUNT
---------- ------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ------------ ------------
       101 2020-06-25 14:06:46 CASH                                               CREDIT CARD                                                12          1.9         22.8
       102 2020-06-24 14:07:29 DEBIT CARD                                         CREDIT CARD                                                21         2.99        62.79


SQL>
```

Edit:I have no idea about apex but if you decide to create the table without virtual column you can add label box or non editable text box item and use formula to display calculation for apex forms run time

Comment: thank you, sam i will try these solution and will notify later if i can solve it or not